# Jquery Load and get result in string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load

I try use Jquery, for using load function, call url ang get the result

**First i use this simple php code, called from url and load with Jquery, the file has the name test.php :**

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST['send_test']=="ok")
{
$result="fine";
}

?>
```

**By other side i have the Jquery script inside index.php, for call to test.php :**

```
<div id="loader"></div>


<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#loader").load("test.php?send_test=ok");


/// Here the question ///

if($result=="fine")
{
alert("Value it´s Fine");
}
else
{
alert("Value Different");
}
 /// Here it´s the central question, how get this, i know, sure bad writte but put, for people understand what i need


});

</script>
```

In this little script, with Jquery, i try get the result from load, when call to test.php, the first code i put here, but in my case i don´t know how i must do, for get "$result" value, for use inside Jquery Script

This it´s my question, i hope understand me, thank´s in advanced

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where `$result` is defined. I would think you would look at the content of `jQuery("#loader")` instead.

Comment: Yes right i need get this value when jquery inside index.php, call to test.php y get in string this value, in this case value it´s "fine", but my question it´s about what i need for get this result from load inside jQuery script if($result=="fine"), ..... i put that code as example for understand more my central question

Comment: You're not on the right path. [jQuery Load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) _load[s] data from the server and place[s] the returned HTML into the matched elements_. As Twisty suggests, you'll have to look into jQuery's ajax functions (for which `.get()` is shorthand for a GET http request).

Answer (score 1):

I would advise looking at `$.get()` instead. Here is an example.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.get("test.php", {
    send_test: "ok"
  }, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result == "fine") {
      alert("Value is Fine");
    } else {
      alert("Value is Different");
    }
  });
});
```

See More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/